# Management Data Warehouse SQL Server data collection reports

Tags: sql-server, data-collection

I configured MDW on an SQL Server instance but when I try to access the reports from the MDW DB, the reports show information until a couple of days ago and I am getting 'collection set is not running. The data displayed here is from a previous run' as per below:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [enable Data Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/enable-or-disable-data-collection?view=sql-server-2017)

> **Using SQL Server Management Studio**
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, expand the Management node.
> 2. Right-click Data Collection, and then click Enable Data Collection.

or **Using Transact-SQL**

```
USE msdb;  
GO  
EXEC dbo.sp_syscollector_enable_collector;
```

FYI, MDW works using SQL Agent jobs, so the Agent has to be started and collector's jobs have to be enabled.

Comment: I have already done this

Comment: Have you [started the Collection Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/start-or-stop-a-collection-set?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: yes, data is being collected but I am getting that error in red for disk usage collection. Also Server Activity data collection is failing but query statistics is working perfectly